# Almacenar información mediante un constructor con parámetros de tipo clase

Tags: java, poo, clase, herencia, polimorfismo

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio:

> En un puerto, se aquilan amarres (espacio de estacionamiento) para barcos. Para cada alquiler, se almacenan el nombre, el número de cliente, el número de días de alquiler, la posición del amarre y el barco que lo ocupa. Un barco se caracteriza por su registro, su eslova (en metros) y el año de fabricación. Los barcos diferencian según su tipo y características en:
>
> - Veleros: número de mástiles.
> - Barcos deportivos: potencia en el motor.
> - Yates de lujo: potencia en el motor y número de cabinas.
>
> El costo de alquiler se calcula multiplicando el número de días de ocupación por el costo diario, que varía según el tipo de barco:
>
> - Para veleros se calcula multiplicando el número de mástiles por $ 15.
> - Para barcos se calcula multiplicando los metros de eslova por $ 35.
> - Para los yates se calcula multiplicando el número de cabinas por $ 17.
>
> ---
>
> 1. Utilizar la herencia para implementar las clases y sus relaciones.
> 2. Genere una clase de prueba que:
>
>    - Introduzca la información para cada tipo de barco.
>    - Usando polimorfismo calcular el alquiler pagado por el cliente.
>    - El uso de una interfaz muestra los datos de cada uno de los tipos de barcos.

He realizado el siguiente código, pero tengo algunas preguntas. En principio tengo que crear una clase de prueba tal que el usuario pueda ingresar información para cada uno de los tipos de barcos (veleros, yates de lujo, embarcaciones) y ya introduje esa informacion, pero no como lo esperaba.

Yo quería enviar toda la información del barco velero mediante el constructor de la `class Renta`, i.e. `Renta(String nombre, String posicion, int numDias, int numCliente, Barco barco)`, pero no sé cómo enviarle información mediante el atributo `barco`, entonces para solucionar el problema cree una `interface` y así ya pude almacenar e imprimir los datos del barco velero.

```
interface Adicional {
    String muestraDatos();
    double costoRenta();
}

class Renta implements Adicional {

    private String nombre, posicion;
    private int numDias, numCliente;
    private Barco barco;

    Renta() {
    }

    Renta(String nombre, String posicion, int numDias, int numCliente, Barco barco) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.posicion = posicion;
        this.numDias = numDias;
        this.numCliente = numCliente;
        this.barco = barco;
    }

    public String muestraDatos() {
        return nombre + " " + posicion + " " + numDias + " " + numCliente + " " + barco;
    }

    public double costoRenta() {
        return 0;
    }

    String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    String getPosicion() {
        return posicion;
    }

    int getNumDias() {
        return numDias;
    }

    int getNumCliente() {
        return numCliente;
    }

    Barco getBarco() {
        return barco;
    }

    void setNombre(String n) {
        nombre = n;
    }

    void setPosicion(String p) {
        posicion = p;
    }

    void setNumDias(int n) {
        numDias = n;
    }

    void setNumCliente(int n) {
        numCliente = n;
    }

    void setBarco(Barco barco) {
        this.barco = barco;
    }
}

abstract class Barco {

    private int matricula, year;
    protected double eslova;//en metros

    Barco(int matricula, int year, double eslova) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
        this.year = year;
        this.eslova = eslova;//longitud del barco

    }


    public double costoRenta() {  
        return 0;
    }            

    public String muestraDatos() {

        return matricula + " " + year + " " + eslova + " ";
    }
}

class Velero extends Barco {

    private int numMastiles;

    Velero(int matricula, int year, double eslova, int numMastiles) {
        super(matricula, year, eslova);
        this.numMastiles = numMastiles;
    }

    public String muestraDatos() {
        return super.muestraDatos() + " " + numMastiles;
    }

    public double costoRenta() {
        return 15 * numMastiles;
    }
}

abstract class BoteConMotor extends Barco {

    protected double potenciaMotor;

    BoteConMotor(int matricula, int year, double eslova, double potenciaMotor) {
        super(matricula, year, eslova);
        this.potenciaMotor = potenciaMotor;
    }

    public String muestraDatos() {
        return super.muestraDatos() + " " + potenciaMotor;
    }
}

class Embarcaciones extends BoteConMotor {

    Embarcaciones(int matricula, int year, double eslova, double potenciaMotor) {
        super(matricula, year, eslova, potenciaMotor);
    }

    public double costoRenta() {
        return 35 * eslova;
    }
}

class YateLujo extends BoteConMotor {

    private int numCamarotes;

    YateLujo(int matricula, int year, double eslova, double potenciaMotor, int numCamarotes) {
        super(matricula, year, eslova, potenciaMotor);
        this.numCamarotes = numCamarotes;
    }

    public String muestraDatos() {
        return super.muestraDatos() + " " + numCamarotes;
    }

    public double costoRenta() {
        return numCamarotes * 17;
    }
}

public class AlquilacionBARCOS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner r = new Scanner(System.in);

        Renta s = new Renta();
        Barco b[] = new Barco[3];

        System.out.println("Introduzca la informacion para el barco velero\n");
        System.out.println("nombre del cliente");
        String nam = r.nextLine();
        s.setNombre(nam);
        System.out.println("num. de cliente");
        int n = r.nextInt();
        s.setNumCliente(n);
        System.out.println("num. de dias de renta");
        int m = r.nextInt();
        s.setNumDias(m);
        System.out.println("posicion de amarre");
        r.nextLine(); 
        String p = r.nextLine();
        s.setPosicion(p);
        System.out.println("matricula:");
        int q = r.nextInt();
        System.out.println("eslova:");
        double w = r.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("year de fabricacion:");
        int k = r.nextInt();
        System.out.println("num. de mastiles:");
        int v = r.nextInt();

        b[0] = new Velero(q, k, w, v);
        System.out.println(b[0].muestraDatos() + " " + b[0].costoRenta()+" "+s.muestraDatos());
     }
}
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿cómo enviar toda la información sobre algún tipo de barco mediante este constructor `Renta(String nombre, String posicion, int numDias, int numCliente, Barco barco)`?

Comment: `Barco deportivo` es equivalente a `Embarcacion`

Comment: Hola Michelle, esto es una tarea?

Comment: :D si, porque? @Jorgesys Lo vez muy facil, o muy dificil, o muy como?

Comment: Pues si es una tarea como comentas, si la veo dificil...

Comment: hmm pero pues ya casi esta (a menos de que este mal hecha), solo tengo esa pregunta sobre enviar datos mediante el constructor..y ya @Jorgesys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar, déjame darte un consejo: **Es difícil revisar 200 líneas de código**. Si reduces un poco el código que has posteado (por ejemplo quitando todos esos setters y getters, y la interacción con el usuario) será más fácil ayudarte.

Además, el que hayas incluido el enunciado de tu ejercicio da a entender que requieres de más ayuda. Si ése es el caso y no hay información en SO, puedes formular otra pregunta. Puedes buscar más información en el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

En cuanto a tu pregunta, lo que pides en el enunciado suena a [Inyección de dependencias](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_de_dependencias). La inyección de dependencias consiste en **proveer a un objeto de todos los objetos que necesite, en vez de obligarlo a instanciarlos por sí mismo**. El ejemplo que se da en Wikipedia utiliza un patrón de diseño que quizá es demasiado para tu ejercicio, pero puedes implementarlo de otras formas:

```
Renta renta = new Renta(nombre, posicion, numDias, numCliente, 
    new Velero(/*Si el usuario quería un velero*/);
Renta renta = new Renta(nombre, posicion, numDias, numCliente, 
    new YateLujo(/*Si el usuario quería un yate*/);
```

En este caso, instanciando el `Barco` en cuestión de forma anónima en la llamada al constructor de la `Renta`.

### El problema

El problema con tu código es que **necesitas saber cuántos barcos y de qué tipo quiere el usuario antes de siquiera instanciar la clase Renta**.

### Mi recomendación

Mi recomendación es que rediseñes tu código. <s>Probablemente la clase `Renta` pueda ser desechable</s> (**EDITADO**: Se necesita crear una renta por barco), Y puedas crear una jerarquía del siguiente estilo:

```
interface Adicional {
  public abstract void mostrarDatos();
}
abstract class Barco implements Adicional {
    int matricula; //anteriormente registro
    int year;
    double eslova;
    public abstract int calcularCoste();
}
class Velero extends Barco {
    int numeroMastiles;
}
class BarcoAMotor extends Barco{
    int potenciaMotor;
}
class Yate extends BarcoAMotor{
    int numeroCabinas;
}
```

Tu clase Renta podría ser así:

```
class Renta {
    private String nombre, posicion;
    private int numDias, numCliente;
    private Barco barco;

    public Renta(String nombre, String posicion, int numDias, int numCliente, Barco barco) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.posicion = posicion;
        this.numDias = numDias;
        this.numCliente = numCliente;
        this.barco = barco;
    }

    public int calcularCoste() {
        return this.barco.calcularCoste();
    }
}
```

De esta manera, mediante polimorfismo, podrás sacar el cálculo de la renta y los datos para cualquier tipo de barco que crees. La implementación con Inyección de dependencias podría ser así (**EDITADO**: Anteriormente se usaba una lista de `Barco`):

```
List<Renta> rentas = new ArrayList<>();

//nuevas rentas EDITADO: se invocaba a add() sin instanciar una nueva Renta
rentas.add(new Renta("John", "Primera", 3, 1, new Velero(/*parametros del velero*/)));
rentas.add(new Renta("Doe", "Segunda", 1, 2, new Yate(/*parametros del yate*/)));

//calcular el coste de cada renta
for (Renta renta : rentas) {
    renta.calcularCoste();
}
```

Comment: Y que tendría que ir en `int registro`? En donde quedaron las variables para el nombre del cliente, numero de cliente, etc.?

Comment: @Michelle Editado.

Comment: me marca un error en la linea `renta.add(...)` el error es: _no suitable method found for add(String, String, int,int,Barco)_ y hay mas texto

Comment: @Michelle EDIT: He vuelto a editar la respuesta. Me había equivocado en el último fragmento de código.

Comment: Y ahora en el output me aparece `null null 1 0 null 15`, es decir no me imprime los atributos de Renta. Y este es el codigo de imprimir que tengo:  `b[0] = new Velero(q, k, w, v);` 
 `rentas.add(new Renta(nam,p,m,n,b[0]));`
 `System.out.println(s.muestraDatos() + " " + b[0].costoRenta());` qUe programa tan latoso :D verdad jaja..

Comment: Lo siento, pero el código que pones no es muy explicativo...¿Qué son `s, q, k, w, v, nam, p, m n`....? ¿Dónde llamas a ese `System.out.println`? A modo de consejo, procura siempre que los nombres de tus variables y métodos expliquen qué son o qué hacen. Idealmente una persona que no supiera de programación debería poder leer tu código y saber qué está pasando.

Comment: `Renta s=new Renta()`, q=matricula, k=year de fabricacion, w=eslova,v=num. de mastiles,..., todo esta en la clase main de mi programa, el cual esta en mi pregunta

Comment: el `System.out.println` esta en la clase main

Answer (score 2):

Tienes las bases, sólo me enfocaré en tu pregunta, ten en cuenta que al extender de una clase en este caso Barco las diferentes clases que extiendan de ella en este caso los tipos tienen como padre la misma clase abstracta y pueden ser enviados a través del parámetro en el constructor o función, por ejemplo

```
public void Renta(String nombre, String posicion, int numDias, int numCliente, Barco barco) {};

public void MiFuncion() {
    // TODO: Que hare con cualquier barco.
    Velero velero = new Velero(0, 0, 0, 0);
    Embarcaciones embarcaciones = new Embarcaciones(0, 0, 0, 0);

    Renta renta1 = new Renta("Nombre", "1", 1, 1, velero);
    Renta renta2 = new Renta("Nombre", "1", 1, 1, embarcaciones);
}
```